# Expose Serializable Enum attributes in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to to expose an Enum from my WCF class (basically as a mechanism for passing a constant). When I look at the service reference code or the WSDL there is no sign of the Enum and I cannot use it. Why not?

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class MyRequest
{
    [DataContract]
    public enum Constants
    {
        [EnumMember]
        MaxMaxArticles = 1000
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you haven't *used* the enum anywhere in the contract. Unless you have, there is no reason that it would be included in the graph that it builds by walking members from the root contract type. It will not be included *just* because it is nested: it needs to be *actually used somewhere*.

Comment: You mean I need to put the Enum in either a member of the Request or the Reponse? I'm purely using it to avoid having to declare a constant in two places. Is there a better way?